# RadWindow Restriction Zone (Full Screen - Browser)

Tags: radwindow

I want to set a parameter for RadWindow Restriction Zone.

I do not want to move outside of the browser window.

How to block move the window outside the browser?

How to set the Restriction Zone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestrictionZoneID property of the radwindow to resolve your problem. Reference this post at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/restrictionzone/defaultvb.aspx